# Read and Interpolate data from NetCDF file throws shape mismatch error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, netcdf, netcdf4

I have this netcdf file with data having latitude, longitude and temperature. The temperature has the dimension 103x61 in terms of latitude and longitude. I want to resize this 103x61 grid to 70x70 by applying nearest interpolation. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# load data from netCDF file
nc_file = Dataset('data.nc', 'r')
lat = nc_file.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc_file.variables['lon'][:]
temp = nc_file.variables['temp'][:]

# create new grid
new_lat = np.linspace(lat.min(), lat.max(), 80)
new_lon = np.linspace(lon.min(), lon.max(), 80)
new_lat, new_lon = np.meshgrid(new_lat, new_lon)

# flatten lat, lon, and temp arrays
lat_flat = lat.flatten()
lon_flat = lon.flatten()
temp_flat = temp.flatten()

# interpolate to new grid
new_temp = griddata((lat_flat, lon_flat), temp_flat, (new_lat, new_lon), method='linear')

# save new_temp to npy file
np.save('new_temp.npy', new_temp)
```

But this produces the following error:

> ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (103,) and arg 1 with shape (61,).

I know there is a mismatch between height and width but I can not afford to clip the data from any side to fit into square grid and then interpolate it. Is there a way to get around this error?

Comment: Can you post the netCDF file somehow?

Comment: already solved. thanks :) I used xarray library.

Answer (score 0):

Here's How I solved it:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

temp = xr.open_dataset('data.nc')['temp']

lat = temp['latitude'].values
lon = temp['longitude'].values
new_lat = np.linspace(np.min(lat), np.max(lat), 80)
new_lon = np.linspace(np.min(lon), np.max(lon), 60)

new_temp = temp.interp(latitude=new_lat, longitude=new_lon, method='nearest')

new_temp = new_temp.to_numpy()
np.save('new_temp.npy', new_temp)
```